# Replace Sonicwall TZ series

Tags: vpn, router, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

What are some devices that i could use to replace several TZ series devices. The only function i really need is the Site-to-Site VPN. Preferably not a Sonicwall device they have the worst support I ever came across.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Astaro Security Gateway](http://www.astaro.com/).  They have a line of products which will serve as firewall as well as a VPN gateway.  They also have a remote-office zero-configuration site-to-site VPN device which looks really nice.  I use their firewall product (ASG220) in our data center (a pair of them in a HA configuration) and have had good success with them over the last few years.

Comment: Will do I just requested a demo unit from them to test out. Thannks